# Can I open a named pipe on Linux for non-blocked writing in Python?

Tags: python, linux, named-pipes

I created a fifo file using `mkfifo`. Is it possible to open/write to this without blocking? I'd like to be agnostic whether there is a reader or not.

The following:

```
with open('fifo', 'wb', 0) as file:
    file.write(b'howdy')
```

Just stalls at the open until I do a `cat fifo` from another shell. I want my program to make progress regardless there's a data consumer watching or not.

Is there a different linux mechanism I should be using perhaps?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From `man 7 fifo`:

> A process can open a FIFO in nonblocking mode.  In this  case,  opening for  read-only will succeed even if no-one has opened on the write side yet, opening for write-only will fail with ENXIO  (no  such  device  or address) unless the other end has already been opened.

So the first solution is opening FIFO with `O_NONBLOCK`. In this case you can check `errno`: if it is equal to `ENXIO`, then you can try opening FIFO later.

```
import errno
import posix

try:
    posix.open('fifo', posix.O_WRONLY | posix.O_NONBLOCK)
except OSError as ex:
    if ex.errno == errno.ENXIO:
        pass # try later
```

The other possible way is opening FIFO with `O_RDWR` flag. It will not block in this case. Other process can open it with `O_RDONLY` without problem.

```
import posix
posix.open('fifo', posix.O_RDWR)
```