# python script hangs when writing to /dev/xconsole

Tags: python, python-3.x

my python script is supposed to write to `/dev/xconsole`. It works as expected, when I am reading from `/dev/xconsole`, such as with `tail -F /dev/xconsole`. But if I don't have `tail` running, my script hangs and waits.

I am opening the file as follows:

```
xconsole = open('/dev/xconsole', 'w')
```

and writing to it:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    xconsole.write(line)
```

Why does my script hang, when nobody is reading the output from `/dev/xconsole` ?

Comment: Try opening it for a non-blocking writing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754397/can-i-open-a-named-pipe-on-linux-for-non-blocked-writing-in-python

Comment: Read this - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139490/continuous-reading-from-named-pipe-cat-or-tail-f

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/dev/xconsole` is a named pipe and it is on demand `FIFO` pipe.

So when you use it, it stores data in memory as Linux provides an object of fixed size. If the application doesn't read the data timely, then the buffer becomes full and the application hangs.

In order to avoid this, you'll need to Write > Read > Write  and so on. Just ensure that it doesn't fill up. For a Linux system it's around 64KB usually.

Comment: how could I increase the size ? I am happy to recompile the kernel, if necessary.

Comment: @Martin This might help you with increasing size of the pipe. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229529/319193 or smassey has provided a Python snippet to increase size down below.

Answer (score 2):

@Vishnudev summarized this nicely already and should be accepted as the correct answer. I'll just add to his answer with the following code to resize your FIFO memory buffer:

```
import fcntl

F_SETPIPE_SZ = 1031
F_GETPIPE_SZ = 1032

fifo_fd = open("/path/to/fifo", "rb")
print(f"fifo buffer size before: {fcntl.fcntl(fifo_fd, F_GETPIPE_SZ))}"
fcntl.fcntl(fifo_fd, F_SETPIPE_SZ, 1000000)
print(f"fifo buffer size after: {fcntl.fcntl(fifo_fd, F_GETPIPE_SZ))}"
```